# How to disable ringer off warning?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

Multiple times a day my Android device will pop up this annoying alert that the ringer is disabled and that I might miss calls.  I have the ringer off on purpose and the device doesn't even have phone capability.  Seems to have started with the last security update to Android 6 (maybe a month ago?).  How can I disable this annoying popup?

Comment: Is that a regular notification? Could you please post a screenshot of this popup?

Answer (score 1):

Disable the app Peel remote. Find the app and disable it.